# como puedo cambiar una variable POST a float

Tags: php, javascript, php7

buen dia trato de guardar un formulario con un porcentaje este mismo ya tengo un codigo el cual es el siguiente

```
$cnv= (1-($sdo_total/$mont_pagar))*100;
```

ahora al hacer el insert la tabla me dice NAN cosa que me dijeron que se deben pasar los datos del tipo float como el siguiente ejemplo

```
$de_desc = (float)$de_desc;
```

mi duda es como puedo hacer que se guarden con el porcentaje correcto sin que me diga NAN
DEJO MI insert com la variable que e mencionado $cnv la cual me guarda como NAN EN PHPMYADMIN

```
$sql="INSERT INTO convenio (usuario, fecha_soli, cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt, sdo_total, mont_pagar, de_desc, fecha_pago, tipo_solicitud,estatus) 
VALUES  ('".$_SESSION['usuario']."','$fecha_soli', '$cuenta', '$fecha_prom', '$nombre_tt','$sdo_total' ,'$mont_pagar','$cnv', '$fecha_prom', '$tipo_solicitud','Pendiente')";
```

y las variables las que quiero convertir a float cada que escriben en un input tipe text

```
$sdo_total=!empty($_POST['sdo_total']) ? $_POST['sdo_total'] : NULL;
$mont_pagar=!empty($_POST['mont_pagar']) ? $_POST['mont_pagar'] : NULL;
```

de ser posible tambien busaco meterlo en la actualizacion
cada que alguien actualice

```
$query2 = "UPDATE convenio SET  usuario='".$_SESSION['usuario']."',fecha_soli='".$_POST['fecha_soli']."',cuenta='".$_POST['cuenta']."',fecha_prom='".$_POST['fecha_prom']."',nombre_tt='".$_POST['nombre_tt']."',sdo_total='".$_POST['sdo_total']."',mont_pagar='".$_POST['mont_pagar']."',de_desc='".$_POST['de_desc']."', fecha_pago='".$_POST['fecha_pago']."',tipo_solicitud='".$_POST['tipo_solicitud']."',actualizado_a=NOW(),estatus='".$_POST['estatus']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'];
```

agrego el error de linea 35

$cnv =(1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100;
y el resultado del insert

INSERT INTO convenio (usuario, fecha_soli, cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt, sdo_total, mont_pagar, de_desc, fecha_pago, tipo_solicitud,estatus) VALUES ('Rmendoza','2020-06-08', '95665', '2020-06-23', 'recuerdos forever jifid',' 5312055' ,' 790000 ','-572.41202531646', '2020-06-23', 'convenio','Pendiente')

Answer (score 0):

Ya estaba contestando esta pregunta antes de que la borraras. Y si, el problema que tienes es que como las variables son enteras, al calcular el descuento te sale siempre cero. La solución es super sencilla:

```
$cnv = (1-(floatval($sdo_total)/$mont_pagar)*100;
```

Y ya estás. `floatval()` no es casting de `float`, es una función que interpreta lo que le das, por ejemplo dos strings como `100.25` y `100,25` regresarían el mismo valor.

[Documentación de `floatval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval)

---

Sobre tu pregunta específica:

```
$sdo_total  = !empty($_POST['sdo_total'])  ? floatval($_POST['sdo_total']) : NULL;
$mont_pagar = !empty($_POST['mont_pagar']) ? floatval($_POST['mont_pagar']) : NULL;
```

---

No tengo ni idea de cuál es tu línea 35, pero parece que no estás pasando un numérico. hay que ver qué le estás pasando por post, a ver, hasta el principio de tu página escribe:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); die(); ?>
</pre>
```

...y pones la salida

---

El problema en la base de datos, creo que debería ir en otra pregunta. Yo hago esto para capturar mis errores en sql:

```
$q = "SQL Query";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die(mysqli_error($db) . "<br>$q");
```

¿Puedes poner el resultado del error Y el query (no el que estás formando, sino el que se está yendo a la base de datos)?

```
INSERT INTO convenio (usuario,        fecha_soli, cuenta, 
                      fecha_prom,     nombre_tt,  sdo_total, 
                      mont_pagar,     de_desc,    fecha_pago, 
                      tipo_solicitud, estatus) 
                     VALUES 
                     ('Rmendoza',     '2020-06-08',              '95665', 
                      '2020-06-23',   'recuerdos forever jifid', ' 5312055',
                      ' 790000 ',     '-572.41202531646',        '2020-06-23', 
                      'convenio',     'Pendiente')
```

El formateo fue para poderlo leer bien.

este es el resultado y edite la publicacion

Comment: Habías preguntado con otro sentido, pero era básicamente lo mismo. ¿El floatval() no te funcionó?

Comment: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\convenios\conv.php on line 35
que lo comvierta

Comment: A ver, en tu descripción pon las asignaciones: `$saldo=100; $monto=10;"  A mi me funciona perfectamente

Comment: $MONTO A PAGAR =7,900.00  
$SALDO TOTAL  =53,120.55
=85%
es que si me da cuando le doy echo 
$cnv = (1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100;

pero cuando lo inserto no me agarra

Comment: Ah, ese es otro problema diferente. Ni había visto tu código de la inserción

Comment: Pon el valor de `$sql`, no como se arma

Comment: es el insert la variable $sql 
"INSERT INTO convenio (usuario, fecha_soli, cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt, sdo_total, mont_pagar, de_desc, fecha_pago, tipo_solicitud,estatus) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['usuario']."','$fecha_soli', '$cuenta', '$fecha_prom', '$nombre_tt','$sdo_total' ,'$mont_pagar','$cnv', '$fecha_prom', '$tipo_solicitud','Pendiente'

Comment: La verdad es que no voy a leer eso. Mira, después de la asignación escribes una línea que diga `die($sql)` y pones el resultado.

Comment: guardadoINSERT INTO convenio (usuario, fecha_soli, cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt, sdo_total, mont_pagar, de_desc, fecha_pago, tipo_solicitud,estatus) VALUES ('Rmendoza','2020-06-08', '95665', '2020-06-23', 'recuerdos forever jifid',' 5312055' ,' 790000 ','-600', '2020-06-23', 'convenio','Pendiente')

Comment: quieres que haga de nuevo la pregunta? una nueva espesificando los errores mas el insert que hago mas el formato que necsito para mysql?

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos estás usando? En mySQL no debería darte problemas. Supongo que los campos de fecha son de datetime, date o timestamp.

Comment: El problema no está en los numéricos. Está en las fechas. ¿La línea 35 es la de inserción a la base de datos?

Comment: SI, si ponlo en una pregunta nueva, y pon más contexto, estas líneas parece que no son el único problema. Si esto está dentro de una función, pon la función completa, o incluso la página completa desde el `<?php` hasta el código de inserción.

Comment: ya la publique 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367549/problemas-con-float-en-php