# problemas con float en php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, numberformat

Buen dia tengo un problema el cual es que tengo una variable
es la siguiente

```
$cnv =(1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100;
```

y mi insert es el siguiente

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO convenio (usuario, fecha_soli, cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt, sdo_total, mont_pagar, de_desc, fecha_pago, tipo_solicitud,estatus) 
    VALUES  ('".$_SESSION['usuario']."','$fecha_soli', '$cuenta', '$fecha_prom', '$nombre_tt','$sdo_total' ,'$mont_pagar','$cnv'(este es la variable), '$fecha_pago', '$tipo_solicitud','Pendiente')";
```

ahora mi base de datos es

```
    7  sdo_total         float          
    8   mont_pagar  float
    9   de_desc  float
```

lo que necesito es que me saque un porcentaje el cual sale de la división de monto a pagar y saldo total y el *100
que lo hace ya esta variable

```
$cnv =(1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100;
```

pero me guarda otro numero ya que por ejemplo
si hago estos numeros en excel

```
Saldo total 53.120.55
monto a pagar 7900.00
=100%-(monto a pagar/saldo total)
y me da en excel %85
```

ahora lo que me da en php es lo siguiente

guardado

```
INSERT INTO convenio (usuario, fecha_soli, cuenta, fecha_prom, nombre_tt, sdo_total, mont_pagar, de_desc, fecha_pago, tipo_solicitud,estatus) 
VALUES ('Rmendoza','2020-06-30', '674651', '2020-06-30', 'complementos','53.120.55' ,'7900'
```

Me da este resultado:

```
'99.327594936709', '', 'convenio','Pendiente')
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué valor estás mandando a guardar? ¿qué valor se guarda? ¿de qué tipo es la columna de la base de datos donde guardas el dato?

Comment: `$cnv =(1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100` A menos que esté entendiendo mal tu fórmula, está incorrecta, debería ser `$cnv =(1-(floatval($mont_pagar) /$sdo_total)) *100`. mont_pagar=7900, sdo_total=53120.55

Comment: este es el resultado que busco

Comment: <?php

$sdo_total = 7900;
$mont_pagar = 53120.55;

$cnv = (1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100;

echo number_format($cnv);

?>
mira

Comment: y me dice esto 
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\convenios\conv.php on line 35

Comment: No veo fallo en la fórmula, ¿qué tienes en la línea 35 de tu archivo conv.php?

Comment: $cnv =(1-(floatval($sdo_total) /$mont_pagar)) *100
solo me sale cuando escribo puntos y comas en las variables de los inputs $sdo_total y $mont_pagar
pero aun no me guarda el porcentaje correcto

Comment: Puede ser la configuración de decimales, los tienes con `,` o `.`?

Comment: no se en la BD lo tengo como float entonces cuando lo inserta lo ponercon el descuento mas punto extra %90.2194

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que PHP tal vez no pueda convertir "53,122.55" (esto sería un string) en "53122.55" (esto sería un float). No escribas en el input comas.

Comment: y si necesito que sea string con comas por que hago misgraciones como podria guardarlo en phpmyadmin que formato

Comment: Entonces tendrías que hacer algún método de apoyo que reciba un string ("53,122.55")  y te devuelva un float (53122.55)

Comment: vale gracias are otra pregunta

Comment: Necesitas poner más código, desde el inicio hasta la inserción, como te comenté en la otra pregunta, creo que tiene que ver en el cómo estás manejando las fechas. Los números parece que no son el problema.

Comment: `floatval` puede manejar cosas como `53122.55` y `53,122.55`, incluso `53.122,55`, es bastante inteligente

Answer (score 0):

Estoy viendo que la configuración de tu equipo está mal

```
Saldo total 53.120.55
```

¿qué número es ese? Si estás pasando ese número, evidentemente va a estar mal todo, porque no se puede parsear en un número correcto, y si le pasas eso a la base de datos, te va a reventar, y los cálculos antes van a estar mal, etc. etc.

Por eso te digo que pongas el código completo, no solo fragmentos, de verdad es imposible ver cómo lo estás haciendo si solo pones líneas aisladas.

Comment: si de hecho quiero pasar decimales para que me haga el porcentaje de otra forma solo quitando los puntos y comas me agarra el numero correcto